# Sending Push Notification to a Windows phone from Linux Server

Tags: linux

Can we send a push notification to a windows phone from a linux server or is this bound to a windows server only?

Comment: If we can write a code in java to push on windows phone then it could be run on linux server and we can make a push from linux server using java.

Comment: Does your data from web server go to a Windows Phone app? Do you push your data from server or pull data from WP7?

Comment: Yes i tried my data to push from web server to windows phone app but now i got the solution (written below) and it is working perfectly fine for me.Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i got the answer...

Make a http post to the Subscription URI

**Java Code:**

String toastMessage = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" +

```
  "<wp:Notification xmlns:wp=\"WPNotification\">" +
     "<wp:Toast>" +
          "<wp:Text1> Welcome To Windows Push &lt;/wp:Text1>" +
     "</wp:Toast> " +
  "</wp:Notification>";


byte[] notificationMessage = toastMessage.getBytes();

url = new URL(subscriptionURI); //You must have the subscription URI provided by MPNS to client side.

HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.setRequestProperty("ContentLength", String.valueOf(notificationMessage.length));
connection.setRequestProperty("ContentType", "text/xml");
connection.addRequestProperty("X-WindowsPhone-Target", "toast");
connection.addRequestProperty("X-NotificationClass", "2");

connection.connect();

DataOutputStream out = 
    new DataOutputStream(
        connection.getOutputStream());
out.write(notificationMessage, 0, notificationMessage.length);
out.close();
```